# Add the generation date in all Typo3 pages

Tags: debugging, typo3

I have a Typo3 application and I'd like to have a comment in the HTML source of all pages showing the date they were generated (for debugging purpose: we have multiple Varnish and multiple Typo3 instances) Something like that:

```
 <!-- generated by TYPO3: 2014/09/25 at 11:23:15 -->
```

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic thing would look like this (assuming your page object is called `page`, headerData.10 is unused otherwise):

```
page.headerData.10 = TEXT
page.headerData.10 {
    stdWrap {
        data = date: U
        strftime = %Y/%m/%d at %H:%M:%S
        noTrimWrap = |<!-- generated by TYPO3: | -->|
    }
}
```

There is a caveat however: Different parts of the page can have different ages. They could be non-cached, or non-cached by the core and then cached with the `stdWrap.cache` property, or many other things. So this might not give accurate results.

If you want to update each time the page is delivered by TYPO3 itself (even if TYPO3 only delivers a cached result), wrap the code above into a `COA_INT` content object to remove it from caching:

```
page.headerData.10 = COA_INT
page.headerData.10 {
    10 = TEXT {
    10 {
        stdWrap {
            data = date: U
            strftime = %Y/%m/%d at %H:%M:%S
            noTrimWrap = |<!-- generated by TYPO3: | -->|
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't wrapping it in an `COA_INT` render Varnish useless as it would make any page non-cachable (if TYPO3 is configured to send the correct cache headers)?!

Comment: Sounds interesting, I'll give a try next week. Thank you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

TypoScriptFrontendController already does something similar for your:

If TypoScript `config.debug` or `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['debug']` is on, something like the following string is rendered on the bottom of the page:

```
<!-- Cached page generated 11.07.20 12:37. Expires 18.07.20 12:37 -->
```

(Note that these settings also do a bit more such as adding a `X-TYPO3-Parsetime` header.)